# Expanding UITextView inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

There are more than a dozen questions on SO that are similar but there doesn't seem to be any consensus on the best way to do this. Additionally I haven't found any solution that worked for me. The thing that is different with my custom UITableViewCell is that I've two labels, one of which is in it's own view, and a text view. All three of which should expand to their content.

I'm wondering if I just have my constraints set up incorrectly, but I'm not sure what I'd adjust.

Here is my cell in IB.

[image: cell in IB]

The content view is light red, the extra view at the top is white with a label inside it.

When the text changes I save the text and update the `tableView`:

```
-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    NSLog(@"row: %i", textView.tag);
    [self.textStrings setObject:textView.text atIndexedSubscript:textView.tag];
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

For the `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method I'm using cached values for the heights except for the selected row. In that case I'm creating a new cell, configuring it, and grabbing the height with `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:`. This seems to be the most common [solution](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2014/02/14/table-view-cells-with-varying-row-heights.html).

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // use cached height if there is one (and it isn't the selected row)
    if ([self.selectedRow integerValue] != indexPath.row && indexPath.row < [self.rowHeights count]){
        return [[self.rowHeights objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] floatValue];
    }

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"RMTextViewCell";
    RMTextViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    [self configureCell:cell forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell layoutIfNeeded];

    CGFloat height = [cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;
    height += 1; // add 1 for border

    NSNumber *h = @(height);
    [self.rowHeights setObject:h atIndexedSubscript:indexPath.row];

    return height;
}
```

The textView does expand but when it goes to multiple lines the top label starts to be clipped. In some versions I've had the textView start clipping/expanding when the text changes. It seems that autolayout isn't sure how to properly calculate the height for the cell.

Any ideas?

Here is my [Github project](https://github.com/ryanjm/ColorTilt) it has a few experiments inside there. The important files are `ViewControllers/RMTextViewTableViewController` and `Cell/RMTextViewCell`. If you run it check out "Dynamic Cells with Text."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem. UILabel in UITableViewCell calculate is correct, but UITextView in UITableViewCell calculate is incorrect.

So only calculate the height manually with:

```
CGSize textViewSize = [cell.textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(cell.textView.frame.size.width, FLT_MAX)];
```

Comment: How do you add to that the rest of the cell since the labels could also be multiple lines?

Comment: Finally figured it out. I'll post more details about how I did the calculations at some point in the future. Thanks.

Comment: Can u post these details RyanJM? I have the same problem

Comment: Ditto, same Problem here, would be really great if you can post your solution!

Answer (score 2):

Seems like this may be an iOS bug because I would expect that the UITextView's height would be included as a UILabels is when it is in the contentView of a cell and we use systemLayoutSizeFittingSize. Anyway, as user501836 said, you can just calculate the height of the textView manually. You then need to add that to the height calculated for your contentView. Here is an example of how I calculated the cell height in tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    CGFloat height = [cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;

    CGSize textViewSize = [[cell textView] sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake([[cell textView] frame].size.width, FLT_MAX)];

    height += textViewSize.height;

    return height;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution that would work in both iOS7 and iOS8. Building on jobb's answer above, I added some code to handle rotation using UITextView.contextSize vs. UITextView.frame.size.

I also found that in xCode 6 it seemed like systemLayoutSizeFittingSize was accounting for the UITextView's textContainerInsets. So I found setting those to zero before adding the additional height to systemLayoutSizeFittingSize did a better job of setting the spacing.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Get the cell once and save it in an NSDictionary. Thisupports cases with multiple cells types.
    CCTextViewCell *sizingCell = [self.offscreenCells objectForKey:CellIdentifier];
    if (!sizingCell) {
        sizingCell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        [self.offscreenCells setObject:sizingCell forKey:CellIdentifier];
    }

    [self populateCellViewWithData:sizingCell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    sizingCell.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, CGRectGetWidth(tableView.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(sizingCell.bounds));
    [sizingCell setNeedsLayout];
    [sizingCell layoutIfNeeded];

    // UITextViews don't autosize well with systemLayoutSizeFittingSize.
    // We need to add the sum of the heights of the UITextViews without its textContainerInsets to the height.
    // We also need to set the textContainerInsets to zero so that systemLayoutSizeFittingSize give the right number.
    // So we do this first.
    CGFloat additionalUITextViewsHeight = 0;
    for (UIView *subVw in sizingCell.contentView.subviews) {
        if ([subVw isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]]) {
            UITextView *subTextView = (UITextView*) subVw;

            subTextView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
            CGSize textViewSize = [subTextView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(subTextView.contentSize.width, FLT_MAX)];
            additionalUITextViewsHeight += textViewSize.height;
        }
    }

    CGFloat height = [sizingCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height + additionalUITextViewsHeight;

    return height;
}
```